# Microsoft graph people\me return empty list of users

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

I have created an account in the Office 365 trial. I've added the New App Registration on Azure with permissions:

```
BookingsAppointment.ReadWrite.All 
Calendars.ReadWrite
Contacts.ReadWrite 
EWS.AccessAsUser.All
Mail.ReadWrite 
Mail.Send 
People.Read 
User.Read 
User.ReadBasic.All
```

And when I call https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/people as the user who created the office account gets a full list of users and resources.

When I call as a created user by admin with administrator rights, I get an empty list.
I call permission link on admin user and on created admin user:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id={}&response_type=code&scope=BookingsAppointment.ReadWrite.All%20Calendars.ReadWrite%20Contacts.ReadWrite%20EWS.AccessAsUser.All%20Mail.ReadWrite%20Mail.Send%20People.Read%20People.Read%20User.Read%20User.ReadBasic.All
```

What is wrong?

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('fb6b188c-8698-4a03-9da4-82b7479c4625')/people",
    "value": []
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a user (lets call it Admin in your case) to be able to access another users contacts folder using the delegate grant would require Contacts.Read.Shared or Contacts.ReadWrite.Shared see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-get-shared-contacts-folders .

The other thing is that Admin rights have no meaning to mailbox access eg Delegate Access to mailboxes all needs to be specifically granted either via Add-MailboxPermission https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/recipients/mailbox-permissions?view=exchserver-2019 or delegate through Outlook. (eg if you can access the target mailbox through OWA or Outlook your Exchange rights are good but just being a Tenant Admin means in regards to mailbox access). Your other option is if your trying to create an app that is going to access all mailboxes in a tenant look at app only tokens https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-daemon-app-registration

Comment: Thanks, can you tell me, after adding a new user and doing everything correctly, does the office need a few hours to synchronize data? Sometimes, for example, after a few hours, he can start working properly.

Comment: Yes there is some synchronization of the back-end Active Directory services so for instance making changes to the Mailbox permission generally take 15 minutes to take affect I've found but I've seen instances where it can take much longer.